# plt.imshow() custom ticks at set Y values [Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I need to mark certain regions on my mosaic. I have plotted horizontal lines, but would like to be able to set a tick value of the value next to them. something like '0.1, 0.2, etc'

I have added an example of the picture below.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,20))
plt.imshow(cube1_img_rot)
plt.imshow(cube2_img_rot, extent=[-19,1928,-24537, -22591])
plt.imshow(cube3_img_rot, extent=[-19,1928,-9352, -7476])

for i in range(len(mu_pix)):
    plt.axhline(mu_pix[i])
plt.savefig('foo.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `ax.set_yticks()`?

Comment: I tried that but I can't quite get that to work. How would you put it if you wanted a tick at y=0,500,800,1000 ?

Comment: Literally, `ax.set_yticks([0,500,800,1000])`. Or in your case rather `plt.yticks([0,500,800,1000])` if you don't have an  `ax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

```
ax.set_yticks((                 1559.43068618,   1175.83793458,    522.94553171, -422.02772895,
                                -1696.91470316,  -3364.08381994,  -5532.01302058, -8414.16763989,
                                -12558.01658595, -23564.41909972,      0.        ))
labels = ax.set_yticklabels((0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1))
```